# Saving UIDocument locally

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to save a UIDocument locally (for when the user has iCloud turned off). This is proving to be a challenge. Every time I try to save it, the save fails. Are there any errors I can access? Does anybody have any idea why this would fail? Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference between UIDocument and UIManagedDocument?

Comment: Here, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933055/uidocument-openwithcompletionhandler-crash and also a tutorial to check your workflow http://www.raywenderlich.com/12779/icloud-and-uidocument-beyond-the-basics-part-1

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on UIDocument:

```
- (void)handleError:(NSError *)error userInteractionPermitted:(BOOL)userInteractionPermitted
```

> This method is called by the default implementations of openWithCompletionHandler: and saveToURL:forSaveOperation:completionHandler: when UIDocument encounters a reading or writing error, respectively.`

If you implement this method you should be able to examine the NSError in there to determine the cause of the failure.

Comment: I am using the saveToURL method, which calls the method you mentioned. This method does not have any error information however

Comment: @ClintWarner: Look at handleError:userInteractionPermitted: in the documentation for UIDocument.  Answer edited.